# Extract nested nested JSON array in Presto

Tags: arrays, json, presto

Say I have a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"attributes":{"blah":"bleh","transactionlist":[{"ids":["a","b","c","d"]}]}}
```

I've attempted to extract the ids (a,b,c,d) into rows in Presto. From looking at other resources, it seems I should be casting the "ids" element into a map and then array, and unnest eventually. However, I am having some trouble doing this as the "ids" element is nested within a nested element. Anyone have any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `ids` element in an JSON array nested in another JSON array, you need to `UNNEST` twice:

```
presto> SELECT id
     -> FROM (VALUES (JSON '{"attributes":{"blah":"bleh","transactionlist":[{"ids":["a","b","c","d"]}]}}')) t(x)
     -> CROSS JOIN UNNEST (CAST(json_extract(x, '$.attributes.transactionlist') AS ARRAY<JSON>)) u(transaction)
     -> CROSS JOIN UNNEST (CAST(json_extract(transaction, '$.ids') AS ARRAY<varchar>)) z(id)
     -> ;
 id
----
 a
 b
 c
 d
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will give this a try and see how it goes.

Comment: Update: Thanks for your help - very helpful to see the query laid out and expected result.