# Presto: JSON extract multiple layers

Tags: arrays, json, presto, cross-join, unnest

[image]

I am trying to extract, under each service the name and state under inspections (multiple of them). I have tried

```
TRANSFORM(CAST(JSON_PARSE(json_format(json_extract(json_extract(services_data, '$.services'), '$.inspections'))) AS ARRAY<JSON>), x -> JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(x, '$.title')) AS inspection,
```

Is there a way to do it? I checked the other questions posted on the same, but do not see these complex layers.

Comment: You may find https://stackoverflow.com/a/52605659/65458 helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your piece of data, added some more stuff to it for testing, and came up with this SQL query:

```
with example(record) as (
    values(json '{"services":[{"category_id":1,"completed":true,"created_at":"2020-01-27T20:44:57Z","hazmats":[],"inspections":[{"created_at":"2020-01-27T20:44:57Z","detail":null,"inspection_id":10209887,"name":"Accelerator Pedal","state":"green","updated_at":"2020-01-27T20:44:57Z"},{"created_at":"2020-01-27T20:44:57Z","detail":null,"inspection_id":10209887,"name":"Accelerator Pedal 2","state":"orange","updated_at":"2020-01-27T20:44:57Z"}]},{"category_id":1,"completed":true,"created_at":"2020-01-27T20:44:57Z","hazmats":[],"inspections":[{"created_at":"2020-01-27T20:44:57Z","detail":null,"inspection_id":10209887,"name":"Some dummy name","state":"navy","updated_at":"2020-01-27T20:44:57Z"}]}]}')
)

select name, "state"
from example
cross join unnest(cast(json_extract(record, '$.services') as array<json>)) as u(service)
cross join unnest(cast(json_extract(service, '$.inspections') as array(row(name varchar, "state" varchar)))) as x(name,"state");
```

Result looks like this:

```
name                |   state
------------------------------
Accelerator Pedal   |   green
Accelerator Pedal 2 |   orange
Some dummy name     |   navy
```

It looks to me like what you are after.